# DNS and mail server actions for restoring web access to mails

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server

A domain name, say `example.com`, is registered to company ONE. The Address record of the DNS for that domain has been changed, to map `example.com` with an IP of a server of company TWO. Consequently, `example.com` is now hosted to TWO, but the mail hosting is still done in the mail server of ONE. Since then, web access to mails under `example.com` is not possible. Which server actions between ONE and TWO should take place in order to restore mail web access?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> A domain name, say example.com, is registered to company ONE. The Address record of the DNS for that domain has been changed, to map example.com with an IP of a server of company TWO.

It doesn't matter to whom a domain name is registered. The registrant is simply responsible (among other matters) for setting the *nameservers*, the machine(s) which are listed as authoritative in the parent DNS namespace for any DNS queries pertaining to the `example.com` domain.

It is unclear from your description whether you have modified the *nameservers* for `example.com`, or if you have only changed the `A`/`AAAA` record in the root of the zone. My answer will vary depending on which has occurred.

---

## 1. Nameservers (`NS` records) changed

If you changed the nameservers, then **ANYTHING** pertaining to a request involving `example.com` will now be resolved by company two's nameservers. You will have lost *all* records previously in the `example.com` zone, including such records as your `MX` records (used to find the machines which should receive inbound email) and any such record as `mail.example.com` or `webmail.example.com`, which you may have used to access web e-mail with the previous provider.

You will need to contact the previous provider and ask them to send you the DNS modifications required so that your mail still continues to work. I suspect this will be at least the following changes:

- add an `A` record (and possibly `AAAA` if they're IPv6-enabled) for their mail server, mapping to the ISP's IP address.
- add an `MX` record to indicate where mail should be delivered
- add one or more `A`/`AAAA` records for access to a POP3, IMAP, SMTP and web-email service.

Note that this is not a robust configuration if you do not manage the mail infrastructure. The ISP could modify their mail system at any time. Their customers whose DNS they manage will have the changes propagated automatically, while your system will simply break, and require manual changes in the `example.com` DNS namespace for the system to work again.

As such, many ISPs may not even be receptive to such a setup, and are highly unlikely to support it. If this was the change you made, I would suggest you revert back to using company 1 for your nameservers, and just point relevant records at company two for whatever services they host on your behalf (see route 2, below).

---

## 2. `A`/`AAAA` records changed

If you modified the `A` (and possibly `AAAA`) records for `example.com`, `www.example.com` and any other services you wish to point to company 2, *but company 1 is still the manager of the nameservers*, then something else is the problem if you lost access to email.

Of course, if your email used a URL like `http://example.com/webmail` then that will have broken, as `example.com` is now handled by company 2. However, if it used `webmail.example.com` or some such address, then ordinarily that would not be an issue. It may, however, be the case that this aliases to `example.com` or one of the other records which is now resolved by company 2, meaning the traffic is still ending up at company 2.

I should also point out as a passing comment that there is a lesser known option for `MX` records involving a [fall-back to `A` records should an `MX` not be found](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record#History_of_fallback_to_A). If you were previously relying on this for the *delivery* of email, then this will also have broken if you modified `example.com`'s root record. This is an unlikely configuration I haven't seen for a long time, but I point it out for completeness.

Comment: the second case is true, e.g. A reocord for foo.com, has been changed to point to company 2. You stated the problem correctly: There is no access to mails through http://foo.com/webmail and it is obvious why. The question though remains, what should be done? I was told something like that company 2 should use the IP of the mail server's for foo.com to map it to foo.com..but it's not clear to me.

Comment: Company 2 could run a reverse proxy, and proxy any traffic for `example.com/webmail` over to the original location where that resided at company 1, while still answering non-webmail traffic themselves. Or, you could ask company 1 to create a new record, e.g. `webmail.example.com` which goes directly to their webmail service and bypasses this difficulty. The latter would be the preferred option, and is not an unreasonable ask; many people want to host their website separately to their email service so binding them both to the root domain is not a suitable long-term strategy.

Comment: Crystal clear now. I 'm gonna go with the second option, seems to me more standard. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem at all!